# How to bind multiple class in vueJs

Tags: vue.js

I want to bind multiple class by vueJs but the code does not work. I am following the vue documentation of class binding topics. I am not able to find my error.

```
<a href="#" :class="[badge, badge-primary, ladda-button]>
```

Comment: You need quotes around your strings. e.g. `'badge-primary'`. Otherwise they are treated as property names and minus signs.

Comment: Tnx bro, I mistake this single cotation as a stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just formatted incorrectly.

`:class="badge badge-primary ladda-button"`

or....

`:class="['badge', 'badge-primary', 'ladda-button']`

Comment: Yea, I got my mistake. Afterall tnx a lot.